# What is the minimum to parse HTML in headless mode?

Tags: java, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am part of the EUvsVirus hackathon this weekend scraping the web for scientific articles.  COVID-19 in unknown HTML and many require a headless browser. 
What is the minimum software that needs to be installed to do this? I will be distributing as a commandline utility, maybe in Docker. If I use Chrome do I have to install the browser? I will want to distribute the result widely and don't want complex or proprietary installation.

(https://github.com/petermr/openVirus)

Comment: You need eg chrome, know-how to run in in headless mode and something to controll it from your app - Selenium

Comment: This is a commandline (added that, thanks), not an app.